Is the sentence "the shirt is washed" correct or often used?
When I look up words in dictionaries, sometimes I see the past participle form of some verbs used as an adjective but not all (verbs).
1-The boy breaks his toys every day (active action).
2-his toys are broken every day by him (passive action).
3-his toys are broken (the current state of his toys) ** (the adjective "broken" here expresses the current state of the toys that are in pieces because of being dropped/smashed...)
Similarly,
4-I rumple the shirt (active action).
5-the shirt is rumpled by me (passive action).
6-the shirt is rumpled (current state of the shirt)
My question is that:
Can all transitive verbs be used this way?
7-I wash the shirt
8-the shirt is washed by me
9-the shirt is washed (sounds wrong)
Do we say "the shirt is washed" to express the current state of the shirt the same way we say "the shirt is rumpled"?
Also why does "the shirt is rumpled" sound okay?
why doesn't "the shirt is washed" sound okay?
Similarly, does "eaten" in "the cake is eaten" refer to the state of the cake?

We don't normally identify shirts as "washed" (as opposed to "unwashed"?). We have clean shirts and dirty shirts (or "shirts that need washing / to be washed"). The reason is probably just that washed primarily refers to an "action" that was done in the past, whereas rumpled primarily refers to a current "state".

@FumbleFingers I have got in arguments here before because I don't see any problem with saying that someone or something is gone, eaten, washed, etc. Old-fashioned, maybe, literary possibly, but not howlingly either, and defintely not 'wrong'.

Maybe not laundry, but you could be in a high-school chemistry lab washing test-tubes as a punishment for deliberately mixing chemicals to make a terrible smell to disrupt the class. The teacher comes in and points to a rack of them and asks "Are these washed?" Or your brother is looking in the fridge for a slice of leftover pizza. You say, "Sorry, it's eaten"

@MichaelHarvey,TimR: I never intended to imply there's anything wrong with using the past participle of such "primarily active" verbs adjectivally. But, for example, In the case of test tubes of indeterminate status, I think I'd be much more likely to ask "Have you washed these?" Or maybe "Have these been washed?" Or the pizza, "Sorry, I ate it."

As I mentioned in a comment on Tom's similar question on ELU, half-eaten is a more likely adjectival use than eaten.

Did you ask a similar question a couple of days ago about "V3 verbs"? It looks like it has been deleted.

@Barmar, you must be thinking of this question on EL&U: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/627937/can-v3-form-of-any-verb-be-used-as-an-adjective-to-express-a-current-state-if-n

The short answer is no, not all verbs can be used this way correctly. The difference is in verbs that are actions vs verbs that are states of being. Some verbs can be both, and can thus be used this way. Other verbs are only one or the other and thus cannot.
Washed is not commonly used as a state of being. As noted in the comments, clean is the state of being that something becomes if it has been washed. This is different from the word rumpled which can be both a state of being and an action.
A note on dialects and formality
Dialects may disagree on which words can be used as states of being vs actions. We see in the comments that people disagree about washed as a state of being, because speakers in different regions may use these differently.
In addition, informal speech allows many more words to be used as a state of being than formal speech or writing does. Formal English often has more restrictive rules. So the context matters on whether something is or isn't natural-sounding.

Certainly, in context, I and others would be likely to say "The shirt is washed," or more specifically, "That shirt was washed." Imagine a situation where someone is about to put a shirt in a washing machine, and it shouldn't be washed again --it's already clean.
